# Rails, extra row in a view for nested object. (updated)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-table, nested, iteration

there!

*update*: https://github.com/czepesch/gloss - made repo public.

subject: I need to remove or prevent one extra empty row in a view (in a table).

I have two models in my RoR app: **Glossary** and **Entry**

```
class Glossary < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entries
```

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :glossary
  
  validates :term, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Form for adding **entries** to **Glossary**:

```
  = form_with(model: [@glossary, @entry], local: true) do |f|
    - if @entry.errors.any?
      - @entry.errors.each do |error|
        = error.full_message
      
          = f.text_field :term, :placeholder => 'term'
          = f.text_field :alt, :placeholder => 'alt'
          = f.text_field :target, :placeholder => 'target'
          = f.text_field :def, :placeholder => 'def'
          = f.submit 'add'
```

Table in views/glossaries/show (a bit simplified, I removed tailwind styles for readability)

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th.{:scope => 'col'} term
      %th.{:scope => 'col'} alt
      %th.{:scope => 'col'} target
      %th.{:scope => 'col'} def
      %th.{:scope => 'col'}
        %span.sr-only edit
      %th{:scope => 'col'}
        %span.sr-only delete

  %tbody
    - for entry in @glossary.entries
      %tr
        %td= entry.term
        %td= entry.alt 
        %td= entry.target
        %td= entry.def
        %td
          = link_to edit_glossary_entry_path(@glossary)
        %td
          = link_to [@glossary, entry], data: { 'turbo_method': 'delete', turbo_confirm: "are you sure?" }
```

So, table for any Glossary (even fresh one, without any entries) have one extra empty row:
[extra row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0UEP.png)

I think it is something with **new** action in glossaries_controller:

```
class GlossariesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_glossary, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def index
    @glossaries = Glossary.order(params[:sort])
  end

  def show
    @entry = @glossary.entries.new
  end

  def new
    @glossary = Glossary.new
  end
  
  def edit
  end

  def create
    @glossary = Glossary.new(glossary_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @glossary.save
        format.html { redirect_to glossary_path(@glossary), notice: "glossary was created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @glossary }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @glossary.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @glossary.update(glossary_params)
        format.html { redirect_to glossary_path(@glossary), notice: "glossary was updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @glossary }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @glossary.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @glossary.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to glossaries_url, notice: 'glossary was destroyed' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
    # redirect_to root_path, status: :see_other
  end

  private
    def set_glossary
      @glossary = Glossary.find(params[:id])
    end

    def glossary_params
      params.require(:glossary).permit(:title, :description, entries_attributes: [ :term, :alt, :target, :def ])
    end
end
```

but I can't figure out how to make everything work other way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a record saved that has no data in it? What happens when you click the trash can to delete it?

Comment: No, there is no data in that row. For example, I can create new Glossary, go to it's page and table for entries already have one empty row. At the same time I can check by rails console that glossary do not have any entries at all. Nothing happens when clicking that trash can. It have url on it same as glossary itself http://localhost:3000/glossaries/45

Comment: That is a confusing bug.  For a brand new glossary, on its page what does `@glossary.entries.count` show?

Comment: Also, your git repo does not have any of those files in it, jsut the inital commit files, just an FYI

Comment: Forgot to mention, all recent work in nuki-dev branch.  New glossary have zero entries. But in show method in glossaries_controller I'm using entry = @glossary.entries.new to make my form for entries work (view/entries/_form)

Comment: ok, but just to be clear if you put the code `<%= @glossary.entries.count %>` it shows 0, correct?

Comment: yes, I did add <%= @glossary.entries.count %> to the glossaries/show page and it says '2', but in the table two real rows with entries and one empty row

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
    @entry = @glossary.entries.new
end
```

was causing a 'problem'.
I just added

```
- if entry.save
```

in a view and everything looks fine.

thanks Rockwell Rice for triyng to help.